# Python/MySql good with cursor.execute but not cursor.executemany . 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

Tags: python, mysql, database-cursor, executemany

I have a function that does a mysql inport of a csv file. It was importing line by line but I wanted to speed it up and  create a larger mysql insert using cussor.executemany. In the first version of code, which I used for 6 months, it would loop the document line by line calling the mysql insert once for each line after field splitting that line. Today I modified the function to build a list of lists called `multi_line_rebuild` on the list of lists using `cursor.executemany` instead of `cursor.execute`.  I left the rest of the code the same.  As part of the debug process I did print the `multi_line_rebuild` right before `cursor.executemany` and it looks like a nice list of lists when I debug it.  Also when I switch the code back it works fine.  But when I try to do the larger insert with  `cursor.executemany` it throws an error 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.'  Not sure were to go next in debugging

Full set of errors is

- File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 193, in executemany
  self._get_db().encoding)
- File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 209, in _do_execute_many
  v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
- TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

"""

```
def run_query_with_warnings(warn_type, query_string, **kargs):
   cursor = db.cursor()
   cursor.executemany(query_string, kargs['field_split'])


....main function...
query_string = 'INSERT into ' + table_name + ' (' + report_field_list_reformat_mysql + ') VALUES (%s);' % var_string
run_query_with_warnings(1, query_string, field_split=multi_line_rebuild)
```

---

```
 query_string
'INSERT into tbl_rpt_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ (`item-name`, '
'`item-description`, `listing-id`, `seller-sku`, `price`, `quantity`, '
'`open-date`, `image-url`, `item-is-marketplace`, `product-id-type`, '
'`zshop-shipping-fee`, `item-note`, `item-condition`, `zshop-category1`, '
'`zshop-browse-path`, `zshop-storefront-feature`, `asin1`, `asin2`, `asin3`, 
''`will-ship-internationally`, `expedited-shipping`, `zshop-boldface`, '
'`product-id`, `bid-for-featured-placement`, `add-delete`, '
'`pending-quantity`, `fulfillment-channel`, `merchant-shipping-group`, '
'`update_time`, `user`, `report_id`) VALUES (%s);'

kargs['field_split']
[[b'Bronze',
  b'',
  b'09234VKV44OX',
  b'KL-RZNQ',
  b'34.9',
  b'',
  b'2019-09-09 14:04:42 PDT',
  b'',
  b'y',
  b'1',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'11',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'B0231QB57A',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'B023412315QA',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'NA',
  b'Migrated Template',
  '2019-09-21 22:24:17',
 'adam',
 '16728972805018160'],
[b'3 Patches',
  b'',
  b'07223O5PFP5',
  b'Q2-442RI-MA38',
  b'23.73',
  b'',
  b'2019-07-23 19:26:14 PDT',
  b'',
  b'y',
  b'1',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'11',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'B02342P7TTW',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'B02342MP7TTW',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'',
  b'NA',
  b'Migrated Template',
  '2019-09-21 22:24:17',
  'adam',
  '16728972805018160']]
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and show the output of `print(query_string)` and `print(kargs['field_split'])`. The parameter 2 in `.executemany(...` have to be `seq of seq`

Comment: @stovfl - done...  I dont see anything obivious there, hopefully you or someone else does.   Again this does work if I send this as two queries with cursor.execute

Comment: Your `query_string` is invalid, you have errors at every printed line, which ends with `'` and the next line starts with `'`, e.g. here `, '\n'\`item...` and here `, '\n'\`will...`. 

The shwon `query_string` could not be from inside `run_query_with_warnings` because it has only **one** placeholder, `VALUES (%s)`, which leads to `TypeError: not all arguments...`